# Conditionally use set-retuning function as join clause

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, left-join

## Context

I'm implementing a "job posting" feature that will list jobs available for users. A job can be set for either an interval `start_date` and `end_date` or sparse dates in an array `service_dates`. The availability check should be made using the previously described date information present at the `jobs` model against an `availabilities` model.

Their structures are the following

### jobs

```
        Column          |             Type                               
-------------------------+------------------------------
 id                      | bigint                        
 service_dates           | timestamp without time zone[]
 start_date              | timestamp without time zone   
 end_date                | timestamp without time zone
```

### availabilities

```
        Column          |             Type                               
-------------------------+------------------------------
 id                      | bigint   
 user_id                 | integer                                          
 date                    | date
 spaces_left             | integer
```

When joining then, I wanna cross the job's dates with the matching dates that exist in the `availabilities` table. The problem is that the job's dates are available in two different ways.

For sparse dates I can have it working if I do the following left join:

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN 
    availabilities a 
        ON a.user_id = 1234
        AND a.date in (
          --this will compose a set of the sparse dates
          SELECT UNNEST(j.service_dates)
        )
```

For the `start_date` and `end_date` option this will do the trick:

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN 
    availabilities a 
        ON a.user_id = 1234
        AND a.date in (
          --this will compose a set with the date range between the two dates
          SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(j.start_date::date, j.end_date::date, '1 day'::interval)
        )
```

My problem is that I need to apply either one or another based on the condition of `jobs.service_dates` being present for the particular job record. Originally I thought I could do the following:

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN 
    availabilities a 
        ON a.user_id = 1234
        AND a.date in (
          -- use one or the other based on whether or not there's something on j.service_dates
          CASE cardinality(j.service_dates) > 0
          WHEN TRUE THEN
             (SELECT UNNEST(j.services))
          ELSE
            (SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(j.start_date::date, j.end_date::date, '1) day'::interval)
          END
        )
```

But I get the following error:
`ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

if I try to select from whatever would be returned by the `CASE` statement there I get the follwing:
`ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE`

I think I have what I need in terms of how to logically relate the tables within the scenarios that can be presented already figured out. What I need is a way to conditionally apply either logic.

---

### Update 1

As @Kadet pointed out, `user_id` was missing from the `availabilitites` table so I've added that.
His answer also lead me to accomplish what I wanted, I ended up not going with the exact same solution but I've applied the `CASE` when joining the way he suggested rather than the way I was trying to. There is nothing wrong with his answer, I just didn't use it because there were other particularities with this query that I left out of the question (for simplicity) that would work better with the way I chose. Here's how I did it:

```sql
LEFT JOIN
    availabilities a
      ON a.user_id = 1234
      AND case when cardinality(j.service_dates) > 0
        THEN a.date IN ( SELECT unnest(j.service_dates) )
        ELSE a.date IN ( SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(j.start_date::date, j.end_date::date, '1 day'::interval) )
      END
```

---

### Update 2

An honorable mention to @Ely conceptually his answer is perfectly acceptable and I believe it would be correct. This would not work for me due to details I failed to expose on the first draft of my question, which is, `service_dates` and `start_date` and `end_date` aren't mutually exclusive. The former 2 are always present, being filled with `service_date`'s min and max values. But his idea will probably work for anyone having a similar issue without that particular constraint. So up-vote him if that´s you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This table structure is invalid or incomplete (no user_id field in     availabilities table) but just to show an idea

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN 
    availabilities a 
        ON a.user_id = 1234
WHERE 
   case when cardinality(j.service_dates) > 0
     then a.date = any(j.service_dates)
     else a.date between start_date and end_date
   end
```

or, if generate series is required

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN 
    availabilities a 
        ON a.user_id = 1234
WHERE 
   case when cardinality(j.service_dates) > 0
     then a.date = any(j.service_dates)
     else a.date = any ( select GENERATE_SERIES(j.start_date::date, j.end_date::date, '1 day'::interval))
   end
```

Comment: Yes you're right, I forgot to include the user_id in availabilities, will updated now.
Your response has actually helped me to complete what I wanted. I've used the case as part of the JOIN but using the syntax similarly to yours. I'll also update the description with the solution. Thank you so much @Kadet !

Answer (score 0):

How about an `(A && !B) || (!A && B)` - this is basically what you are trying to achieve. Either the one or the other.

I'd try to translate this to something along the lines:

```
SELECT j.*
FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN 
    availabilities a 
        ON a.user_id = 1234
        AND
        (
          (
            a.date in (SELECT UNNEST(j.service_dates)
            AND (cardinality(j.service_dates) = 0)
          )
          OR
          (
            a.date in (SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(j.start_date::date, j.end_date::date, '1 day'::interval)
            AND NOT (cardinality(j.service_dates) = 0) 
          )
        )
```

There might be syntactic errors. I am not proficient and inspired myself from what you wrote, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Although I see agree that this logic would probably work in my particular case it won't, due to one matter that I forgot to expose in the enunciate, which is that fact that `start_date` and `end_date` will get the min and max values from `service_dates` too. Therefore it will only work conditioned to `service_dates` being `NULL` or not. But I think you're right @Ely. Thank you for you answer!